# Convert month,day,year to month,year with python/pandas?

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas

I have this kind of list of strings with 9000 rows where each row is month/day/year:

```
10/30/2009
12/19/2009
4/13/2009
8/18/2007
7/17/2008
6/16/2009
1/14/2009
12/18/2007
9/14/2009
2/13/2006
3/25/2009
2/23/2007
```

I want convert it and only have the list with month/year if is it possible as dateformat, like this:

```
10/2009
12/2009
4/2009
8/2007
7/2008
6/2009
1/2009
12/2007
9/2009
2/2006
3/2009
2/2007
```

Comment: you could do it with regex `re.sub('/.+/','/', '10/30/2009')` => 
`'10/2009'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can use first [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df.col = pd.to_datetime(df.col).dt.to_period('m')
print (df)
       col
0  2009-10
1  2009-12
2  2009-04
3  2007-08
4  2008-07
5  2009-06
6  2009-01
7  2007-12
8  2009-09
9  2006-02
10 2009-03
11 2007-02

print (type(df.loc[0,'col']))
<class 'pandas._period.Period'>
```

Or [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df.col = pd.to_datetime(df.col).dt.strftime('%m/%Y')
print (df)
        col
0   10/2009
1   12/2009
2   04/2009
3   08/2007
4   07/2008
5   06/2009
6   01/2009
7   12/2007
8   09/2009
9   02/2006
10  03/2009
11  02/2007

print (type(df.loc[0,'col']))
<class 'str'>
```

Or [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) by `regex`:

```
df.col = df.col.str.replace('/.+/','/')
print (df)
        col
0   10/2009
1   12/2009
2    4/2009
3    8/2007
4    7/2008
5    6/2009
6    1/2009
7   12/2007
8    9/2009
9    2/2006
10   3/2009
11   2/2007

print (type(df.loc[0,'col']))
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: Thank you, the best option and more elegant in my opinion is the first that you said. @jezrael

Comment: If I want know the minimum date (2007-02) and the maximum date (2009-12), How can I do it?

Comment: use `print (df.col.max())` and `print (df.col.min())`

Comment: I tried before the comment but not works, it give me an error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date' . My col is called "date".

Comment: I think need `[]`, `print (df['col'].max())`. I think `date` is `method` in pandas, so error. But this works perfect `print (df['date'].max())`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas.Series.str.split) to build the strings:

```
In [32]:
df['date'] =df['date'].str.split('/').str[0] + '/'  + df['date'].str.split('/').str[-1]
df

Out[32]:
       date
0   10/2009
1   12/2009
2    4/2009
3    8/2007
4    7/2008
5    6/2009
6    1/2009
7   12/2007
8    9/2009
9    2/2006
10   3/2009
11   2/2007
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use a regular expression, if you prefer that kind of solution. This would solve your problem:

```
import re

res = re.sub(r"/\d\d?/", "/", s)
```

(Note that `s` is the date string, either as separate date strings or a long string containing all dates, and that you have your result bound to `res`.)